# How to take user input in a class and pass it through a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying make a python script which opens a URL in web browser and now I am facing a error that `NameError: name 'song' is not defined`

```
import webbrowser

class Halsey:
    def__init__(self):
        self.song = song

    def Badland():
        print(" 1.Gasloine" 
        "2.castle" 
        "3.hold me down "
        "4.control")
        song =int(input("Plase select a number from above list"))

if song == 1 :

    url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU3P7qz3ZrM";

    webbrowser.open(url,new=0)
```

Comment: Where did you think `song` would have come from there? It's outside the class and outside the `Badland` method where you take the input. For that matter, where did you think `song` would come from inside the `__init__` method, given that it's not actually a parameter? You should probably review https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0; this is a classic not-a-class.

Comment: i am newbie to programming so i dont know much about it and i am trying to learn programming

Comment: Then I'd recommend a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `song` variable visible only in method `Badland` of your class. So you can use this variable in the same method where you defined it, like this:

```
import webbrowser

class Halsey:

    SONGS = (
        ("Gasloine", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU3P7qz3ZrM"),
        ("Castle", "url2"),
        ("Hold me down ", "url3"),
        ("Control", "url4"),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        for i, song_name in enumerate(self.SONGS, 1):
            print("{}. {}".format(i, song_name[0]))

        song = int(input("Plase select a number from above list: "))
        url = self.SONGS[song - 1][1]
        webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
```

... or you can return user's input from class method and then use it, like this:

```
class Halsey:

    SONGS = (
        ("Gasloine", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU3P7qz3ZrM"),
        ("Castle", "url2"),
        ("Hold me down ", "url3"),
        ("Control", "url4"),
    )

    def get_user_input():
        for i, song_name in enumerate(self.SONGS, 1):
            print("{}. {}".format(i, song_name[0]))

        return int(input("Please select a number from above list: "))

instance = Halsey()
users_choice_int = instance.get_user_input()
url = self.SONGS[song - 1][1]
webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
```

Also, you can save your variable in class attribute: `self.song = int(input(...)` and after that you will be able to access it inside class methods by `self.song`, or outside your class by `instance.song`.

Note: don't forget about potential invalid user input, you can wrap your `song = int(input...` in `try/except`.

Good luck!

Comment: It would be good if you explained the wrong things in the OP's code.